# Retrieving Array of Links with regex - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parse an html page that contains these values:

```
<a href="somesite.html?id=123">...</a>
<a href="somesite.html?id=456">...</a>
<a href="somesite.html?id=789">...</a>
<a href="anothersite.html">...</a>
```

How would I parse the Html String to get back an array of where it only contains the somesite.html:

```
["somesite.html?id=123", "somesite.html?id=456", "somesite.html?id=456"]
```

**Edited**

Using Zhiguo Wang's base answer, I can't seem to get only the somesite.html id values...  The 3rd item in the array contains excess characters:

```
let htmlString = "<a href=\"somesite.html?id=123\">...</a>" +
"<a href=\"somesite.html?id=456\">...</a>" +
"<a href=\"somesite.html?id=789\">...</a>" +
"<a href=\"anothersite.html\">...</a>\""
let seperateComponent = "<a href=\"somesite.html?id="

let linkExp = "[\\w\\W]*\">"
```

Returns this value:

```
["123", "456", "789\\">...</a><a href=\\"anothersite.html"]
```

Expected Value:
    ["123", "456", "789"]

...hmm. Changing linkExp to the below resolves it.  What does \W represent in Regex?

```
let linkExp = "[\\w]*\">"
```

..The length is wrong.  Casted to NSString to grabbed the proper length.

**Edited 2**

It looks like if this string comes first before the somesite, then it includes *Origin* in the array:

```
<meta name=\"referrer\" content=\"origin\">
```

Comment: @Wongzigii I feel like there's an easier solution than a 3rd party library.  E.g all those a tags contain the same format of "somesite.html?id=". Can't regex do a find on those first characters up until the id=, then stop at the first double quotes?  Idk how that would look though

Comment: [`<a href="(.*?)">.*?<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/oH4tY3/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

talk is cheap, show me the code

```
    let htmlString = "<a href=\"somesite.html?id=123\">...</a><a href=\"somesite.html?id=456\">...</a><a href=\"somesite.html?id=789\">...</a>"
    let seperateComponent = "<a href=\""

    let linkExp = "[\\w\\W]*\">"
    let linkRegExp = NSRegularExpression(pattern:linkExp, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    let seperatedArray = htmlString.componentsSeparatedByString(seperateComponent)
    var resultArray = [String]()

    if seperatedArray.count > 1 {
        for seperatedString in seperatedArray {
            if seperatedString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) > 3{
                let myRange = linkRegExp!.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(seperatedString, options:NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, seperatedString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)))
                if myRange.location != NSNotFound {
                    let matchString = (seperatedString as NSString).substringWithRange(myRange)
                    let linkString = (matchString as NSString).substringToIndex(matchString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) - 2)

                    resultArray.append(linkString)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    println(resultArray)
```

these codes have been run on xcode 6.4 and the result is right.sorry " i need at least 10 reputation to post images" so result pic won't be posted here.

Comment: Note that this will crash if the input string contains multiple non-ASCII characters like "ÄÖÜ" or "€". The reason is that counting UTF-8 bytes is *not* the right method to compute an NSRange. Compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches.

Comment: Thanks Zhiguo, I have updated the question to handle one last test case.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work if i set the separatorComponent to:  let seperateComponent = "<a href=\"somesite.html?id="

It includes the other link values.

Comment: Thanks Martin R,that's really a serious situation that i've never thought about.

Comment: And @TimNuwin i know your problem now ,and i'm glad to help
1.\W stands for all the capital characters from A to Z and numbers and other common symbols.
2.if you let seperateComponent = "<a href=\"somesite.html?id=" it won't be right because you separate the last two link together into the same string.
3.sorry i realized that i spelled wrong "separate" :D
4.improved code will be shown below

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expression may go for a toss while parsing HTML files. You have better way of parsing HTML files the iOS way. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) on this. [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) and [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple) are your friends here.

Here is a related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261570/parsing-html-in-swift-other-than-using-regex).

Answer (score 0):

here's the improved code

```
    let htmlString = "<a href=\"somesite.html?id=123\">...</a>" +
        "<a href=\"somesite.html?id=456\">...</a>" +
        "<a href=\"somesite.html?id=789\">...</a>" +
    "<a href=\"anothersite.html\">...</a>\""
    let seperateComponent = "<a href=\""

    let linkExp = "[\\w\\W]*\">"
    let linkRegExp = NSRegularExpression(pattern:linkExp, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    let seperatedArray = htmlString.componentsSeparatedByString(seperateComponent)
    var resultArray = [String]()

    if seperatedArray.count > 1 {
        for seperatedString in seperatedArray {
            if seperatedString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) > 3{
                let myRange = linkRegExp!.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(seperatedString, options:NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, seperatedString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)))
                if myRange.location != NSNotFound {
                    let matchString = (seperatedString as NSString).substringWithRange(myRange)

                    let linkWished = "somesite.html?id="

                    if matchString.componentsSeparatedByString(linkWished).count > 1{

                        var linkString = (matchString as NSString).substringFromIndex(linkWished.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

                        linkString = (linkString as NSString).substringToIndex(linkString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) - 2)

                        resultArray.append(linkString)
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }

    println(resultArray)
```